# Upgrading to Gradle 7.1.1 in Android Studio Breaks Build

Tags: android, gradle

After upgrading to Gradle 7.1.1, I get the following build error:

Unexpected EOF in prolog
at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]

I've done as many Google searches as I could but can't find anything on this. I've tried running the build with stacktrace, debug and scan options but there is nothing in the output window that gives a hint as to where this is coming from, except that it's in this task:

app:mergeProductionDebugResources FAILED

I'm assuming there is some file somewhere that's doing this but I don't know how to begin finding it.

I would like to know if there is some place to look that I'm not aware of, or if there is some procedure to help me track this down.

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue. Someone had added an empty xml file to the project. Previous versions of gradle just ignored this, but 7.1.1 doesn't.